# use jquery to manipulate delete item from select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying using jquery to delete an option from select,

In my case I have more than 4 select items (in some case 10 select)
The scenario that I have to achieve is:

If a user select from the first select the option Toyota so Toyota will be deleted from the three other select

Then if he chooses Nissan from the second select so Nissan will be also deleted from the three other select even the first
Until the last select will show just one option

I have tried the example below it didn’t work 
http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/PGqv7/3/ 
Please help I am beginner with jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>Document sans titre</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( function(){
var sel1 = $('#first'), sel2 = $('#second');

//get the options value/text of some selection

/**
 * get the options value/text map of some select element
 * 
 * @param sel
 *            a select element
 * 
 * 
 * @return {val1:txt1, val2:txt2....}
 */
function getSelOptions(sel) {

    var opts = {}, tmp;
    for ( var i = 0, len = sel.options.length; i < len; i++) {
        tmp = sel.options[i];
        opts[tmp.value] = tmp.text;
    }

    return opts;
}

/**
 * Reset the select element's options
 * 
 * @param sel
 *            the select element
 * @param newOptions
 *            the new options map
 * @param except
 *            the option value which will be excluded
 */
function setOptionsExcept(sel, newOptions, except) {

    //remember the current select value
    var curSel = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;

    //clear the select options
    sel.options.length = 0;

    for ( var k in newOptions) {

        //this one should be excludeed
        if (k != "none" && k == except)
            continue;

        //add to the option list
        sel.options.add(new Option(newOptions[k], k, false, k == curSel));
    }

}

//remember the options map
var opts1 = getSelOptions(sel1.get(0)), opts2 = getSelOptions(sel2.get(0));

sel1.change(function() {

    //sel1 value
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val == "none") {
        //as sel1 is none, reset sel1
        setOptionsExcept(this, opts1);
    }

    //reset sel2, but no sel1 value
    setOptionsExcept(sel2.get(0), opts2, val);
});

sel2.change(function() {

    //sel2 value
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val == "none") {
        //as sels is none, reset sel2
        setOptionsExcept(this, opts2);
    }

    //reset sel1, but no sel2 value
    setOptionsExcept(sel1.get(0), opts1, val);
});

            }
</script>

</head>

<body>


<table>
          <tr>
            <td><select id="first" required>
                <option value="">choisir</option>
                <option value="Profconf">Professeur de Conférence</option>
                <option value="ProfEnsgSup">Professeur d'enseignement supérieur</option>
                 <option value="ProfAssistant">Professeur Assistant</option>
                  <option value="ProfAdjoint">Professeur Adjoint</option>
              </select>
              <input type="hidden" name="designationtypecadre1" value="Professeur_checheurEquivalent "/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><select id="second" >
                <option value="">choisir</option>
                <option value="Profconf">Professeur de Conférence</option>
                <option value="ProfEnsgSup">Professeur d'enseignement supérieur</option>
                 <option value="ProfAssistant">Professeur Assistant</option>
                  <option value="ProfAdjoint">Professeur Adjoint</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="designationtypecadre2" value="Professeur_checheurEquivalent"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><select id="third" >
                <option value="">choisir</option>
                <option value="Profconf">Professeur de Conférence</option>
                <option value="ProfEnsgSup">Professeur d'enseignement supérieur</option>
                 <option value="ProfAssistant">Professeur Assistant</option>
                  <option value="ProfAdjoint">Professeur Adjoint</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="designationtypecadre3" value="Professeur_checheurEquivalent"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table> </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? I selected `Toyota` in first Select and it got deleted from second. Then I selected `Nissan` from second and it got delete from first. Isn't this the required behavior

Answer (score 0):

> If a user select from the first select the option Toyota so Toyota
>   will be deleted from the three other select

try this, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xcnhgm84/)

```
$( '#first, #second, #third, #fourth' ).change(function(){
   //get the selected text
   var selectedText = $(this).find(":selected").html();
   $( '#first, #second, #third, #fourth' ).not($(this)).each( function(){
     $(this).find("option").each( function(){
        if ( $(this).html() == selectedText )
        {
          $(this).remove();
        }
     });
   } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will fill each select with the 'choisir' option as well as with all options not selected in the other selects. Because the base is all start options, choosing another option in another textbox will reappend the original option

```
var selects = $('select'), // or $('#first, #second, #third'), but better would be to use a class
  alloptions = $('#first').children().clone();   

selects.change(function(){  
    var values= selects.map((i,s) => $(s).val()).get();
    selects.not(this).each((si,s)=>{
    var cur = $(s).val();
    $(s).empty()
        .append(alloptions
        .filter((oi, o)=> oi === 0 || o.value === cur || values.indexOf(o.value) === -1).clone())
      .val(cur);
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5m2qm33/)

in the change event, an array with all values is obtained with `var values= selects.map((i,s) => $(s).val()).get();` Then each `Select` except the one that triggered the change event is refilled with all options that confirm to the filter `oi === 0 || o.value === cur || values.indexOf(o.value) === -1`, where oi is the option index and o.value the option value. In other words: index 0 is always included (choisir), the current value of the select and all values not inside the buffered `values` array

PS, if the selects can be filled in runtime, you only have to fill the first select and the other selects can be filled with those same options, as done in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5m2qm33/1/)